# Want to use the function in a select statement

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a function which returns VPHR of an organization :-

```
XX_HR_GENERAL_PKG.XX_GET_SPOC(P_ORG_ID IN NUMBER
                            ,P_SPOC IN VARCHAR2
                            ,P_DATE IN DATE
                            ,P_STRING IN VARCHAR2);
```

Where p_org_id is the organization_id,p_spoc is VPHR ,P_DATE is trunc(sysdate),
p_string is 'employee_number'

```
SELECT DISTINCT aou.name parent_org,
            aou.organization_id organization_id,
            level
      FROM PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS OSE,
           HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS AOU
      where aou.organization_id          = ose.organization_id_child
      and aou.organization_id     not in (:p_org_id)
      start with organization_id_child = :p_org_id
      connect by organization_id_child = prior organization_id_parent
      order by level;
```

Output :-

```
Parent Org              Organization_id   Level
Serviced Portfolio PR   330            2
PR Operations           106            3
```

Now i want that  i use this function  XX_HR_GENERAL_PKG.XX_GET_SPOC(P_ORG_ID IN NUMBER
                                ,P_SPOC IN VARCHAR2
                                ,P_DATE IN DATE
                                ,P_STRING IN VARCHAR2) in such a way that the organization_id which i got above can be used in this function somewhat like this :-

```
 SELECT DISTINCT aou.name parent_org,
                aou.organization_id organization_id,
                level,
                XX_HR_GENERAL_PKG.XX_GET_SPOC(:P_ORG_ID
                                ,'VPHR'
                                ,TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                                ,'emp_num');
          FROM PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS OSE,
               HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS AOU
          where aou.organization_id          = ose.organization_id_child
          and aou.organization_id     not in (:p_org_id)
          start with organization_id_child = :p_org_id
          connect by organization_id_child = prior organization_id_parent
          order by level;
```

error getting :-ORA-06553: PLS-307: too many declarations of 'XX_GET_SPOC' match this call
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: Baby steps.  What happens if you select your function from dual?

Comment: This error implies that you have more than one function in your `XX_HR_GENERAL_PKG` packaged named `XX_GET_SPOC`.  Please edit your question to include the declaration of all such functions from your package header.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as suggested by Luke, please post your specification also for this function.

Secondly, the first select as shown below will list out all those oraganization which are not equal to id's that you passed in this select.

```
SELECT DISTINCT aou.name parent_org,
            aou.organization_id organization_id,
              level
       FROM PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS OSE,
           HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS AOU
       where aou.organization_id          = ose.organization_id_child
       and aou.organization_id     not in (:p_org_id)
      start with organization_id_child = :p_org_id
      connect by organization_id_child = prior organization_id_parent
      order by level;
```

So to use your function for the oraganization id's obtained from your above select, you need to modify your second select as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT aou.name parent_org,
                aou.organization_id organization_id,
                level,
        XX_HR_GENERAL_PKG.XX_GET_SPOC(aou.organization_id
                                ,'VPHR'
                                ,TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                                ,'emp_num');
           FROM PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS OSE,
               HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS AOU
          where aou.organization_id          = ose.organization_id_child
          and aou.organization_id     not in (:p_org_id)
          start with organization_id_child = :p_org_id
          connect by organization_id_child = prior organization_id_parent
          order by level;
```